# How Android interprets @null keyword in layouts?

Tags: java, android

I was digging in sources of Android by looking for an answer of how system recognizes **@null** keyword that mentioned in a layout. For instance,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:background="@null"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

So far I followed this route:

1. [TypedArray#getDrawable(int index)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java#737)
2. [ResourcesImpl#getValue(@AnyRes int id, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/ResourcesImpl.java#184)
3. [AssetManager#getResourceValue(@AnyRes int resId, int densityDpi, @NonNull TypedValue outValue,boolean resolveRefs)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#215)
4. [AssetManager#loadResourceValue(int ident, short density, TypedValue outValue,boolean resolve)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#789)

I tried to find in [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/native/android/asset_manager.cpp) of JNI implementation of **AssetManager** loadResourceValue method, but I have not succeeded.

I would appreciate if anyone can point out how Android resolves @null tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were searching in `AssetManager` frontend that is exposed via NDK. There are no JNI functions at all. JNI wrapper for `android.util.AssetManager` is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp#682).

`ResTable` class is used for actual parsing and resolving. If you dig a bit deeper - you can find [lines](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r3.1/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp#4155) where `@null` is handled.

Comment: Wow, the code looks crazy! Serio, thank you for a reply!